# How do I use LESS variables in my local package?

Tags: meteor

I made a local package to handle the browser implementation of our app.

```
Package.onUse(function(api) {
    api.versionsFrom('1.2.1');
    api.use('angular');
    api.use('twbs:bootstrap', 'web.browser');

    //.... some lines skipped

    api.addFiles([
        'styles/variables.less',
        'styles/forms.less'
    ], 'web.browser');
});
```

In `variables.less` I have one variable declaration: `@gray-light: #E6E6E6;`, and in `forms.less` I have a style declaration that uses the variable. However when I try and compile the app I get the following error:

`While processing files with less (for target web.browser):
packages/app-name-browser/styles/forms.less:6:22: variable @gray-light is undefined`

I don't have the problem when I include the declaration in the same file, so I'm assuming the problem is that `variables.less` is being loaded after `forms.less`. Any way I can remedy this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
Package.onUse(function(api) {
    api.versionsFrom('1.2.1');
    api.use('angular');
    api.use('twbs:bootstrap', 'web.browser');

    //.... some lines skipped

    api.addFiles([
        'styles/variables.less',
        'styles/forms.less'
    ], 'client', {isImport: true});
});
```

And then in you main .less file you can import these files by

```
@import '{your-package:name}/styles/variables.less';
@import '{your-package:name}/styles/forms.less';
```

Comment: Bit late in accepting your answer, sorry about that. This works well, thank you!